# How Can I Get Credit Card Info In sales_order_place_after?

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer

How can I get credit card info (credit card number, expiration date, etc) in a sales_order_place_after observer?

I've tried:

```
$observer->getEvent()->getPayment()
$order->getQuote()->getPayment()->getCcLast4()
$order->getPayment()->getCcLast4()
$order->getPayment()->getCcExpMonth($lastOrderId)
```

And a host of other things, but I can't seem to find the magic formula.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your using a payment method that is similar to magento save cc

```
//Get order 
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()

//Get Payment
$payment = $order->getPayment()

//Get card type
$payment->getData('cc_type')

//Get Payment Info
$payment->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
$payment->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();

//Get Credit Card info
$payment->getMethodInstance()->getCardsStorage()
$cards = $payment->getMethodInstance()->getCardsStorage()->getCards() //array()

foreach($cards as $card){
   Mage::log($card);
}
```

See also [Credit card detail in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583272/credit-card-detail-in-magento)